# How can I grab each value from an Array and compare against a hard coded value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Please review the below code:

```
    var textArray = new Array();
    var allText = results.data._contained.text;
    for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
        var text1 = allText[i];
        var textHtml = "<div id='text_item'>";
        textHtml += "<span class='some_div'>{0}</span>".replace("{0}", text1.text_is);
        textHtml += "</div>";
        textArray.push(text1.texts.priority);

        $("#text_box").append(textHtml);
    }

    if (foo === 'Some text') {
        document.write("match");
    } else {
        document.write("not match");
    }

}
```

In the code above, I am getting values in an array.  And then below that I have this if/else statement.  How can I grab one value at a time from the array and compare against "some text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean?

```
for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
    var text1 = allText[i];
    if (text1 === 'Some text') {
        document.write("match");
    } 
    else {
        document.write("not match");
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well, that's expected. For every item in the array you're comparing to 'Some text' and writing to document. Is the problem that there's no match? You were expecting a match?

Comment: Yup, I was expecting one match which i know exists but not showing.

Comment: Inside the loop `console.log(text1);` (or `document.write(text1);`) and see what the values in the array are to confirm 'Some Text' exists.

Comment: Just remove the whole `else { document.write("not match"); }`